# Difference between bluetoothctl "power off" and kernel "state = 0"

Tags: linux-kernel, bluetooth, bluez

I usually switch off my bluetooth adapter using `bluetoothctl power off`.

Recently, I noticed that `/sys/class/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill0/state` still is `1`, so the kernel considers the bluetooth adapter to be "on"?!

Is the adapter really powered down? What is the difference between the two states?